# Is there any way to change Dropbox's default website in "Launch Dropbox Website" from firefox to Chrome in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, dropbox

I want to change the default browser (firefox) on Ubuntu that opens when I select "Launch Dropbox Website" option on right-clicking the dropbox tray icon. Is there a way / a configuration file where a parameter could be changed?

Comment: I think I have mentioned the OS in my question itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your default browser

1. click *System Settings* in the top right corner
2. click *Details* → *Default Applications*
3. Dropdown menu for *Web* on the right pane → Change your default browser to Chrome

   [image]

Comment: hi, I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and there is "System -> Preferences -> Preferred Applications" where I have already changed my default browser from Firefox to Chrome. But that hasn't helped. Dropbox still opens in Firefox. Does it need a system restart to apply the changes?

Comment: I think your issue is more related to the fact that you can't change your default browser than the fact that dropbox is opening in firefox. What do html documents open in?

Comment: They are opening in Firefox. Hmm, so my default browser hasn't got changed.

Comment: I did sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
and it gave me:
*0  /usr/bin/google-chrome 200 auto mode
That means chrome is the default browser right? I don't know why Firefox is being used as a default.

Answer (score 2):

In XFCE open the MIME type editor, search for html, and you'll be able to change what application is linked with html documents.

Answer (score 0):

In a **Terminal**, `sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser` did it for me.